# You can’t borrow a mutable reference to a read-only value

Tags: rust

I bought the book `Programming Rust: Fast, Safe Systems Development 2nd Edition` a couple weeks ago to learn `Rust`. At the moment, I am struggling with the topic `&T` and `mut &T`.

In the book, the author has mentioned the following regarding to references:

> You can’t borrow a mutable reference to a read-only value.

What does it mean? An example would be nice.

Comment: It means you can never go from `&T` to `&mut T` (safely). E.g. `let x = &5; let y = &mut *x;` won't compile.

Comment: @isaactfa No, you can never go from `&T` to `&mut T`. Period. Safely or not.

Comment: Maybe a bit of context will help us understand what the author means?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman but you [can](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b1d875104d56c551848995d056d5f17f)

Comment: @cafce25 You "can" also create a data race. But this is UB (Miri also flags this).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What about [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html)?

Comment: @cafce25 It *is* UB. Deriving a mutable reference from a shared reference not through `UnsafeCell` is always UB.

Comment: @isaactfa `UnsafeCell` doesn't go from `&T` to `&mut T`, it goes from `&UnsafeCell<T>` to `&mut T` :P

Comment: @cafce25 And [in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#behavior-considered-undefined): "Mutating immutable data. All data inside a const item is immutable. Moreover, all data reached through a shared reference or data owned by an immutable binding is immutable, unless that data is contained within an UnsafeCell<U>."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do the following:

```rust
let a = 99;
let b = &mut a;
```

Comment: If this is what the book means, this is very fragile. Moving the value to a mutable binding can still allow you to mutate it.

Answer (score 0):

In Rust, variables are immutable by default.
You can only borrow variables as mutable *if* those variables themselves are *declared* as mutable.

Consider this example:

```
let x = 42;
let mut y = 42;
let _a = &x;  // This is fine
let _b = &mut x; // This is NOT 
let _c = &y;  // This is fine (even though y is mut)
let _d = &mut y;  // This is fine
```

Also note that it is not possible to have a mutable reference to a standard (immutable) reference to a mutable variable. Example:

```
let mut y = 42;
let r = &y;  // This is fine
let m = &mut r;  // This is NOT (cannot borrow `r` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable)
```